# I am trying to find which fields are null so I can return data from database which has null (non scalar fields)

Tags: mongodb, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I have Categories which has following data model

```
type Category {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
  parentId: Category @relation(link: INLINE)
}
```

In this I want to run query where I can array of Category where parentId is equal to null.

Whenever I try to run query I get all the fields including which are not null.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your needs:

```
query {
  categories(where: {  parentId: null }) {
    name
  }
}
```

And for the not null ones:

```
query {
  categories(where: {  NOT:[{parentId: null }]}) {
    name
  }
}
```